# IIS routes to wrong https site

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

We are running a Microsoft Server 2008 R2 with 2 IP addresses: `.1` `.2` and IIS 7.5 as the webserver.

On this server there is a website configures to use the domain `A.Company.com` on port 80 with IP address unsigned plus https on port 443 to the ip address .2
Additionally there is a second web application using `B.Company.com` on port 80 with IP adress unsigned.
Up to this point everything works as expected.

Now I've added a second SSL certificate for `B.company.com` and an addtional binding for https port 443 using the IP address .1

If I now call `https://b.company.com` I am greeted with a certificate error stating the certificate is issued for `A.company.com`. If I click on visit anyways I am routed to `https://B.company.com` but the website displayed is `A.company.com`. 
I guess I have a crude misconfiguration somewhere but cant figure out where.

To summarize:

Website A:

```
Type    |    Hostname     |    Port    |     IP address
--------------------------------------------------------
http    |  A.company.com  |    80      |    *
https   |                 |    443     |   .2
```

Website B:

```
Type    |    Hostname     |    Port    |     IP address
--------------------------------------------------------
http    |  B.company.com  |    80      |    *
https   |                 |    443     |   .1           //accessing this adress per https://b.company.com gives a certificate error
```

//edit:
There is the possibility, that the routing is f**cked. The webserver is part of our MPLS network, but not located in our company WAN (gotta love the could, right?). If I access it via http the problems described above occur. If I use my smartphone I am getting a password challenge, which looks like it should.
I am investigating further.

Comment: Are you sure your port 443 is only bound to .1 and .2?

Comment: double-checked just now. :443 is used excactly twice as described in my question.